# How to drop multiple columns with similar names in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

My data set has about 100 columns and some of them (about 25) are called similar but not them same. I'd like to delete all columns that start with "reads_per_million" because write this is so impractical:

```
data_tumor <- data_tumor[,-c(3,5,7,13,15,22,33,54,65,34,**etc,etc**)]
```

Thank you so much

Comment: `data_tumor[,-grep('^reads_per_million', names(df))]`

Comment: With `tidyverse`:  `data_tumor %>% 
  select_at(.vars = vars( - starts_with("reads_per_million")))`